# I push my project to gitlab to test git ci,but it built fail

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

These are my information of error

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.5.3 (fb49c47)
Using Shell executor...
Running on luckyxmobiledeMac-mini-2.local...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at e56d7ac Update README.md
Checking out e56d7ace as master...
bash: line 4: shell_session_update: command not found
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 127
```

These are content of my .gitlab-ci.yml:=

```
    stages:
      - build   
    build_project:
      stage: build  

      script:  
        - xcodebuild clean -project ProjectName.xcodeproj -scheme SchemeName | xcpretty  
        - xcodebuild test -project ProjectName.xcodeproj -scheme SchemeName -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s,OS=9.2' | xcpretty -s
      tags:  
        - ios_9-2  
        - osx_10-11
```

Comment: You'll have to show us your `.gitlab-ci.yml` build script as well.

Comment: Do you have access to the server (luckyxmobiledeMac-mini-2.local) the runner is running on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this question on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1062336/461627), this seems to be an issue with the `rvm` package on the server.

You can go read that question and answer for a full explanation of what the issue is, but their solution is to update `rvm` to version 1.26.11 or greater.

To update to the most recent stable version do this:

```
rvm get stable
```

Comment: There are three runners on our server that runs well.

Comment: @superRain Do the other runners use the shell executor and does the build work on those runners?

Comment: Yes, it is because that we use mac. and my gitlab-ci-multi-runner can't run successfully. these are erroe about it.